# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.04.1 via command line?

Tags: upgrade

I have a VM running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and I know that Ubuntu **22.04.1** LTS has been released months ago. Then how can I upgrade to 22.04.1 on the fly, keeping all existing software and configs?

I tried `sudo do-release-upgrade`, but told that `There is no development version of an LTS available.`

[image: do-release-upgrade does not work]

I hope that the answer is suitable to Ubuntu 22.04 running on WSL1 as well, because, there is a weird `/usr/bin/gzip` problem on WSL1, here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8219

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need special commands to upgrade a 22.04 system, the normal

`sudo apt update`

to update your software lists; ie. so your system knows what upgraded packages are available for install, then

`sudo apt full-upgrade`

to apply those security fixes & upgrades.

A reboot maybe required at completion.

The `do-release-upgrade` command is to change from using one release (*jammy* or 22.04 is what you're using now) to upgrade to a later release (eg. *22.10, or the next LTS which will be 24.04 a long time from now*), and isn't used when you're trying to stay on the same *jammy* or 22.04 system you're currently using.

The "*no development version of an LTS available*" message you mention is because the *development* release of 24.04 doesn't open until after 23.10 has been released in October 2023 (and 22.10 is no longer a *development* release being a released or *stable* product).

Comment: I'm not a user of WSL so cannot comment there; but I can't imagine the *developers* doing different for WSL users than the primary products do (*and amending existing documentation that's been in used for decade+*)

Comment: Great. After `sudo apt update`, `apt list --upgradable` says `gzip/jammy-updates 1.10-4ubuntu4.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.10-4ubuntu4]`.  Then `sudo apt full-upgrade` works as expected on WSL1 (costs 10-minutes run) and now `lsb_release -a` reports it is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Most importantly, `/usr/bin/gzip` now works in WSL1.

Comment: Just FYI @JimmChen, there are cases where `apt upgrade` will not apply all upgrades.. (refer to `man apt` to read the difference, but for my release [*lunar*] it reports for `apt full-upgrade` "*full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole*.") .. so I almost always just `apt full-upgrade` to ensure I receive all upgrades,  rarely using `apt upgrade`actually.